# read weighing scale data via RS232

Tags: c#, serial-port

I want to read data from weighing scale data via RS232 and i try any  more way

my weighing scale model yh-t7e [datasheet](https://www.kilogram.cl/content/ficha%20indicador%20Yaohua%20modelo%20T7.pdf)

The output of the scale on the AccessPort program is this value .

[output  on Access Port](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iFkqu.jpg)

**The weight on the scales = 3.900 kg**

**in picture =009.300**

**baud rate 1200**

When I use this code

```
            string s = "";
            int num8 = 0;
            string RST = "";
            while (this.serialPort1.BytesToRead > 0)
            {
                string data = serialPort1.ReadExisting();
                if (data != null)
                {

                    if (data.ToString() != "")
                    {
                        if (data.Length > 6)
                        {
                            RST =  data.Substring(6, 1) + data.Substring(5, 1) + data.Substring(4, 1) + data.Substring(3, 1) + data.Substring(2, 1);

                            this.textBox4110.Text = RST.ToString();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

output in my program

When I use the above code in the program
Sometimes displays the weight number and sometimes does not. I have to open and close the program several times.
And by changing the weight on the scale, its number does not change on the program and the display value is fixed.

and When I use this code

```
 while (this.serialPort1.BytesToRead > 0)
{
int data = serialPort1.ReadByte();
 this.textBox4110.Text = data.ToString();
}
```

**in my program Displays the number 48**

What should I do?

thanks regards

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why your serial port sometimes responds and sometimes doesn't.
I worked with RS232 years ago and never had this problem.

About other questions:

- You're working with a byte array, can't call the ToString, since it will convert to string the byte rappresentation
- If you have to reverse the bites order (4 - 3 - 2 - 1), you can call the Array.Reverse method

Just for make an example about what I mean, I took your code:

```
while (this.serialPort1.BytesToRead > 0)
{
   int data = serialPort1.ReadByte();
   this.textBox4110.Text = data.ToString();
}
```

your "data" variable contains a byte with value 48 that is the 0 char in ASCII table.
So, if you want the char, you have to convert it using the right encoding.
Suppose you are working with UTF8:

```
while (this.serialPort1.BytesToRead > 0)
{
   var dataLen = this.serialPort1.BytesToRead; 
   var byteArray = new byte[dataLen];
   this.serialPort1.Read(byteArray, 0, dataLen);
   var txt = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(byteArray);
   this.textBox4110.Text = txt;
}
```

Honestly I know the Encoding.UTF8.GetString accept a byte array, not sure it will work only with a single byte...

Comment: `while (this.serialPort1.BytesToRead > 0)
{
   int data = serialPort1.ReadByte();
   var txt = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data);
   this.textBox4110.Text = txt;
}`

Error : cannot convert from 'int' to 'byte[]'

Comment: I adapted the example.. try it again

Comment: Thanks for the help
Your code worked, but it displays the numbers one by one.
In this way: If the desired weight is 10,000, then first it shows the number 1 and then it is erased, then the number 0 and then it is erased and so on until the last number.

Comment: Is there a way to fix it?

Comment: Probably you want to read all bytes in one call, not one by one using the ReadByte method. I updated the post. Check it

Comment: I put the code inside a timer and it shows the weight value with each refresh, but it shows a different value each time.
For example, if the weight is 50,000 kg.
The number of places changes with each refresh.
Once 50,000--
Once 050.00--
Once 00.500-- and ....

Comment: First of all, I wrote wrong: in the manual they say to use ASCII, so the right code is Encoding.ASCII.GetString (not UTF8). This change won't resolve your problem, but it is better to use the encoding they say in the documentation. About the value you receive from the serial port, try to debug it and see what the serial port gives you (spaces or escaped chars as well). I can't change what serial port gives you, but it is importanto to understand what serial port will give you to resolve the problem